# ExecuteStreamCommand won't read foreign characters

Tags: java, c#, windows-10, apache-nifi

We have Apache Nifi set to write files to local drive, then run program that processes these files and outputs response to "response" attribute. This is a JSON string that we then deliver to API to update records.

However, issue is that while we can successfully write, read and process the files, Nifi fails to understand non-English characters in the response text. This leads to names being corrupted when we send back the response. This only applies to the JSON string we receive from the program.

Nifi is running Windows 10 environment When we run the program manually using files outputted by Nifi, we get correct output. Issue only happens in Nifi.

To provide example, input json is:

```
{
  "player" : "mörkö",
  "target" : "goal",
  "didhitin" : ""
}
```

This is stored in our programs work folder and we call program using ExecuteStreamCommand , giving our input JSON file as the parameter. JSON is processed and our program outputs following JSON, which is then stored into response attribute of the flowfile:

```
{
  "player" : "mörkö",
  "target" : "goal",
  "didhitin" : "true"
}
```

However, issue is that when this is read by Nifi into the response attribute of the flowfile, it becomes

```
{
  "player" : "m¤rk¤",
  "target" : "goal",
  "didhitin" : "true"
}
```

(Not the actual process, but close enough to demonstrate the issue)

Which, when we feed it into API, would either fail or corrupt the name of the original (In this case, value of player). Neither which is desirable output.

So far, we have figured out that this is most likely issue with encoding, but we have not found a way to change the encoding of Nifi to possibly fix incorrectly read characters.

Comment: to hold non-latin chars in a file you are using some encoding. nifi works with files (and processes) under default windows encoding unless you specify it in `bootstrap.conf` like this: `java.arg.20=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. Tried it and all it did was change ¤ symbols into ? marks. I did add the comment to bootstrap.conf and then restarted NiFi, but issue persists.

Comment: what is the encoding in your console? (use `CHCP` command to check it). Could you redirect output to a file and check that encoding of file still fine... Could you set the output encoding of your app to UTF-8 for example? so, setting utf-8 in nifi would fix the issue... the problem that when you are using windows cmd console - it uses special console encoding...

Comment: CHCP gave me following response:

Active code page: 437

Comment: and redirect ouput to a file from console  `myapp > out.json` ? what is the encoding of the final file?

Comment: Using WriteAllText, encoding is UTF-8. Using >out.json, it is UCS-2 Little Endian. At least, according to NotePad++. Using standard NotePad, it says UTF-16 LE.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue by adding following line to the start of the program:

Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

This effectively enforces the program to output UTF-8 characters, which would be in-line with rest of the flow.